# How to add a running total after each pass in the while loop

Tags: c

I need to figure out how to continuously add to the running total of avg mpg and divide by how many times it goes through.

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
        
int main() { 
    int miles;
    int gallons;
    int mpg;
    int avg;
          
    while (miles != -1) {
        printf("Enter number of miles driven(-1 to quit): ");
        scanf("%d", &miles);
        printf("Enter gallons used: ");
        scanf("%d", &gallons);
        mpg = miles / gallons;
        avg = mpg;
              
        printf("MPG this trip: %d\n", mpg);
        printf("Avg MPG(so far): %d\n", avg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just keep a `total_miles` and `total_gallons`. Initialise both to `0`. Add `miles` and `gallons` to their respective totals. The total average will be `total_miles/total_gallons`.

Comment: within the while loop or outside?

Comment: Well obviously you don't set them to `0` within the loop, so that has to be done before. And you need to add the `miles` and `gallons` each time to their totals, so that part does have to be done within the loop.

Comment: Schelts, what is the value of `while (miles != -1) {` the _first_ time it is executed?  `int miles;` does not assign it any value.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I think I got what you are trying to say, so first of all you should initialize `avg = 0;` and instead of changing `avg = mpg;` every time the loop runs you should do `avg += mpg;` so that it will add the previous values to next time the loop runs, Take another `int` to find the total average, initialize from 0 `int t_avg = 0;` and for next thing, dividing how many times it goes through you should take a variable and initialize it `t = 0;`  and just increment `t` every time the loop runs so you will get the time loop goes on and you just have to divide it with `avg`.
And I would suggest you to use `do while` loop instead of `while` so that would be much better.
Hope this is what you were looking for.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int miles;
    int gallons;
    int mpg;
    int avg = 0, t = 0,t_avg = 0;

    do {
        t++;
        printf("Enter number of miles driven(-1 to quit): ");
        scanf("%d", &miles);
        printf("Enter gallons used: ");
        scanf("%d", &gallons);
        mpg = miles / gallons;
        avg += mpg;
        t_avg = avg/t;
        // adding average every time and diving every time the loop runs
        printf("MPG this trip: %d\n", mpg);
        printf("Avg MPG(so far): %d\n", t_avg);
    }while(miles != -1);
}
```